# Prevent XXE Attack with XStream

Tags: java, security, xstream, xxe

Wanted to know how we can fix Xml EXternal Entity (XXE) vulnerability with Xstream API.

Like we can do

```
// This is the PRIMARY defense. If DTDs (doctypes) are disallowed, almost all XML entity attacks are prevented
// Xerces 2 only - http://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/features.html#disallow-doctype-decl
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
String FEATURE = null;
FEATURE = "http://apache.org/xml/features/disallow-doctype-decl";
dbf.setFeature(FEATURE, true);
```

with DocumentBuilderFactory. More details - https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XML_External_Entity_%28XXE%29_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

My code is something like -

```
public static Class<?>[] myAnnotatedClasses = { Test1.class, Test2.class };

public static Object parseStr(String str) throws XStreamException
{
    XStream xstream = new XStream(new StaxDriver());
    xstream.processAnnotations(myAnnotatedClasses);
    Object obj =xstream.fromXML(str);
    return obj;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [XStream FAQs](http://x-stream.github.io/faq.html#Security_XXEVulnerability):

> `StaxDriver` tries to turns off support for external entities for the standard StaX parser. However, the finally used StAX implementation is defined externally (see JDK documentation) and a test should be made on the target platform to ensure that the parser respects the setting.

What this is saying is that `StaxDriver` tries to tell the `StAX` implementation to do the right thing, but the `StAX` implementation you are using may ignore this.  If it does ignore it, the simple answer is to use one of the alternative drivers listed in the FAQ that doesn't have the problem.

Comment: Makes sense. Will try out with other drivers.  Reports say `StaxDriver` vulnerable for me.